# SQL simple datetime count occurences query driving me crazy!

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, count

Thank you to anyone that can help. I am using MSSQL 2005

I have a database like so

```
SegmentDT DateTime,
WhoCalled varchar(4)
```

All I want to do is find all of the WhoCalled that have a count of calls within 5 minutes of each other.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you add an example with output?  if you had 3 rows, all with whocalled = 'beth' and segmentDT values 1/1/2010 12:00, 1/1/2010 12:01, 1/1/2010 12:02, what results would you expect back?

Answer (score 1):

- You may not need the ABS
- A 5 minute DATEDIFF covers the range 4 mins and 0.003 seconds to 5 mins and 59.997 seconds because of how boundaries are done (zero seconds)
- COUNT(DISTINCT SegmentDT) should remove occurences where you have several calls in a 300 second window

So:

```
SELECT
     WhoCalled, COUNT(DISTINCT SegmentDT)
FROM
     MyTable a
     INNER JOIN
     MyTable b ON a.WhoCalled = b.WhoCalled
WHERE
     ABS(DateDiff(second, a.SegmentDT, b.SegmentDT)) <= 300
```

Another formulation is to use a window function. This will compare adjacent rows:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        WhoCalled, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SegmentDT) AS RowNum
    FROM
        MyTable
)
SELECT
     WhoCalled, COUNT(*)
FROM
     CTE a
     INNER JOIN
     CTE b ON a.WhoCalled = b.WhoCalled AND a.RowNum + 1 = b.RowNum
WHERE
     DateDiff(second, a.SegmentDT, b.SegmentDT) <= 300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WhoCalled, count(*)
FROM tbl a
INNER JOIN tbl b ON a.WhoCalled = b.WhoCalled
AND DateDiff(n, a.SegmentDT, b.SegmentDT) > 0
AND DateDiff(n, a.SegmentDT, b.SegmentDT) <= 5
```